# What is the term for a scenario whereby someone gives an opinion and forces you to agree?

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example a statement which indicates something like "i know if my opinion will generate disagreement, but if it does, it will just make my point stronger".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Lots of people would call it "fascism".

Comment: @Hot Licks ***too right!***

Comment: It would help to have more context and a sentence where you would use it. It's hard to force ~agreement~.  People might have the power to dictate outcomes but that they got their way has nothing to do with agreement.  But perhaps you don't mean "agreement".  If it is a matter of forcing at least support in a vote or something you might say they were "bullied into" support, "wheedled"in to support.  Another might be to say "they wore me down" (they wore my opposition down), or "talked me into it"

Comment: steam roller, hatchet job, bulldoze someone into something. // Please give us the context and a sentence where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for ***railroading***:

> ***[railroad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/railroad)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *informal [with object]* Rush or coerce (someone) into doing something.
>      *‘she hesitated, unwilling to be railroaded into a decision’*
>
>    1.1 Cause (a measure) to be passed or approved quickly by applying pressure.
>      *‘the Bill had been railroaded through the House’*
>
>    1.2 North American Send (someone) to prison without a fair trial.
>      *‘they know I was railroaded and falsely accused’*

Of course, there's also ***badger***:

> ***[badger](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/badger)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Repeatedly and annoyingly ask (someone) to do something.
>       *‘journalists badgered him about the deals’*
>       *‘Tom had finally badgered her into going’*

Or ***harass***:

> ***[harass](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harass)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Subject to aggressive pressure or intimidation.
>      *‘being harassed at work can leave you feeling confused and helpless’*
>
>    1.1 Make repeated small-scale attacks on (an enemy)
>      *‘the squadron's task was to harass the retreating enemy forces’*

See also *[pester](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pester)*, *[hound](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hound)*, and *[nag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nag)*.